# Valid Locale Names

Tags: c++, locale, utf-16

How do you find valid locale names?

I am currently using MAC OS X.
But information about other platforms would also be useful.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        std::wifstream  data;
        data.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-16"));
        data.open("Plop");
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        throw;
    }
}

% g++ main.cpp
% ./a.out
Exception: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Abort
```

Comment: Martin I fixed where you had typoed Local for Locale. I guess you probably know this, but they are different, and if you were typing the wrong one it might have hurt your googling

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This page says:](http://www.cantrip.org/locale.html?seenIEPage=1)

The constructor call std::locale("") creates a locale object that represents the user's preferences. The standard doesn't say what this means, but on many systems the library substitutes whatever is found in an environment variable (often `LANG` or `LC_ALL`) in place of the empty string. A common name for the American locale, for example, is "en_US". **(On POSIX systems you can type `locale -a` to list the names of supported locales.)**

`locale -a` should work for you.

If you mean programatically from the C++ std libary I'm not sure.

[This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745045/stdlocale-breakage-on-macos-10-6-with-langenus-utf-8) is probably also relevant, but he doesn't seem to have had much response.

**Edit**

To use UTF-16 you probably will need to use [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516862/how-do-i-read-unicode-16-strings-from-a-file-using-posix-methods-in-linux).

Comment: That worked: I have en_US.UTF-8 and en_GB.UTF-8. But now I need to decode a UTF-16 file.

Comment: OK, I've extended the answer for that. libiconv is the short answer I think.