# UTF-16 codecvt facet

Tags: c++, locale, utf-16, facet, codecvt

Extending from this questions about [locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922713/valid-locale-names)
And described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207662/writing-utf16-to-file-in-binary-mode): What I really wanted to do was install a codecvt facet into the locale that understands UTF-16 files.

I could write my own. But I am not a UTF expert and as such I am sure I would get it nearly correct; but it would break at the most inconvenient time. So I was wondering if there are any resources (on the web) of pre-build codecvt (or other) facets that can be used from C++ that are peer reviewed and tested?

The reason is the default locale (on my system MAC OS X 10.6) when reading a file just converts 1 byte to 1 wchar_t with no conversion. Thus UTF-16 encoded files are converted into wstrings that contain lots of null ('\0') characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if by "resources on the Web" you meant available free of cost, but there is the [*Dinkumware Conversions Library*](http://web.archive.org/web/20120204111500/http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx) that sounds like it will fit your needs—provided that the library can be integrated into your compiler suite.

The `codecvt` types are described in the section [*Code Conversions*](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx?manual=compleat&page=index_cvt.html#Code%20Conversions).

Comment: The links are dead now. Have the pages been moved elsewhere are have they disappeared entirely?

Comment: After many years, it looks as though they've closed off access to what had been the public documentation for their libraries. That's sad, as it was an excellent resource to study.

Answer (score 0):

As of C++11, there are additional standard `codecvt` specialisations and types, intended for converting between various UTF-*x* and UCS*x* character sequences; one of these may suit your needs.

In `<locale>`:

- `std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>`: Converts between UTF-16 and UTF-8.
- `std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t>`: Converts between UTF-32 and UTF-8.

In `<codecvt>`:

- `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<typename Elem>`: Converts between UTF-8 and UTF-16, where UTF-16 code points are stored as the specified `Elem` (note that if `char32_t` is specified, only one code point will be stored per `char32_t`).

  - Has two additional, defaulted template paramters (`unsigned long MaxCode = 0x10ffff`, and `std::codecvt_mode Mode = (std::codecvt_mode)0`), and inherits from `std::codecvt<Elem, char, std::mbstate_t>`.
- `std::codecvt_utf8<typename Elem>`: Converts between UTF-8 and either UCS2 or UCS4, depending on `Elem` (UCS2 for `char16_t`, UCS4 for `char32_t`, platform-dependent for `wchar_t`).

  - Has two additional, defaulted template paramters (`unsigned long MaxCode = 0x10ffff`, and `std::codecvt_mode Mode = (std::codecvt_mode)0`), and inherits from `std::codecvt<Elem, char, std::mbstate_t>`.
- `std::codecvt_utf16<typename Elem>`: Converts between UTF-16 and either UCS2 or UCS4, depending on `Elem` (UCS2 for `char16_t`, UCS4 for `char32_t`, platform-dependent for `wchar_t`).

  - Has two additional, defaulted template paramters (`unsigned long MaxCode = 0x10ffff`, and `std::codecvt_mode Mode = (std::codecvt_mode)0`), and inherits from `std::codecvt<Elem, char, std::mbstate_t>`.

<sup>[`codecvt_utf8` and `codecvt_utf16` will convert between the specified UTF and either UCS2 or UCS4, depending on the size of `Elem`.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/locale.stdcvt#4)  Therefore, `wchar_t` will specify UCS2 on systems where it's 16- to 31-bit (such as Windows, where it's 16-bit), or UCS4 on systems where it's at least 32-bit (such as Linux, where it's 32-bit), regardless of whether `wchar_t` strings actually use that encoding; on platforms that use different encodings for `wchar_t` strings, this will understandably cause problems if you aren't careful.</sup>

For more information, see CPP Reference:

- [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt)
- [`std::codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8)
- [`std::codecvt_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16)
- [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16)

<sup>Note that support for header `codecvt` was only added to `libstdc++` relatively recently.  If using an older version of Clang or GCC, you may have to use `libc++`, if you want to use it.

Note that versions of Visual Studio prior to 2015 don't actually support `char16_t` and `char32_t`; if these types exist on previous versions, it will be as typedefs for `unsigned short` and `unsigned int`, respectively.  Also note that older versions of Visual Studio can have trouble converting strings between UTF encodings sometimes, and that [Visual Studio 2015 has a glitch that prevents `codecvt` from working properly with `char16_t` and `char32_t`, requiring the use of same-sized integral types instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32055357/5386374)</sup>