# Visual Studio C++ 2015 std::codecvt with char16_t or char32_t

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2015, char16-t, char32-t

This code compiled OK under VS2013:

```
std::string Unicode::utf16_to_utf8(std::u16string utf16_string)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes(utf16_string);
}
```

Now with VS2015 I get:

```
1>unicode.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt<char16_t,char,struct _Mbstatet>::id" (__imp_?id@?$codecvt@_SDU_Mbstatet@@@std@@2V0locale@2@A)
```

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1403302/unresolved-external-when-using-codecvt-utf8

Comment: Yes, I've already googled it, any solutions?

Comment: did you find a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Old question, but for future reference: this is a known bug in Visual Studio 2015, as explained in the latest post (January 7th 2016) in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f40dcd8-c67f-4eba-9134-a19b9178e481/vs-2015-rc-linker-stdcodecvt-error?forum=vcgeneral) of MSDN Social.

The workaround for your example looks like this (I implemented your method as a free function for simplicity):

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#if _MSC_VER >= 1900

std::string utf16_to_utf8(std::u16string utf16_string)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<int16_t>, int16_t> convert;
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<const int16_t *>(utf16_string.data());
    return convert.to_bytes(p, p + utf16_string.size());
}

#else

std::string utf16_to_utf8(std::u16string utf16_string)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes(utf16_string);
}

#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << utf16_to_utf8(u"Élémentaire, mon cher Watson!") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully, the problem will be fixed in future releases, otherwise the `#if` condition will need refining.
UPDATE: nope, not fixed in VS 2017. Therefore, I've updated the preprocessor conditional to `>= 1900` (initially was `== 1900`).

Comment: Well, such an approach from M$ developers is depressing... Imagine you have tons of code you need to rewrite in such a manner...

Comment: That worked for me. How about the opposite direction? If I do an auto p = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(utf8_string.data()); and convert.from_bytes(p) instead, I get that "no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::basic_string<int16_t, std::char_traits<int16_t>, std::allocator<int16_t>>" to "std::u16string" exists"

Comment: found a similar solution and it's reverse at an antlr fix. but not optimal because of two conversions : https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/commit/de6f04be0beebd17ea6232f554635c5262127aaa

Comment: still not fixed in VS 2019 Preview.

Answer (score 9):

Define the missing symbol in a cpp file.

```
// Apparently Microsoft forgot to define a symbol for codecvt.
// Works with /MT only
#include <locale>

#if (!_DLL) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900 /* VS 2015*/) && (_MSC_VER <= 1911 /* VS 2017 */)
std::locale::id std::codecvt<char16_t, char, _Mbstatet>::id;
#endif
```

Comment: VS2017: error C2491: 'std::codecvt<char16_t,char,_Mbstatet>::id': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Comment: Indeed it does not compile with **/MD**, because the foreign DLL would have no way of knowing/using our definition. It does work with **/MT** though. So it is only half a workaround :-)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in VS2017:

```
std::wstring utf8_to_utf16(std::string utf8_string)
{
   return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t>{}.from_bytes(utf8_string);
}

std::string utf16_to_utf8(std::wstring utf16_string)
{
    return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t>{}.to_bytes(utf16_string);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible workaround is to use default second template parameter (wchar_t) for wstring_convert. It is working for "MS Visual Studio 2015 update 3". Please note that it is **not platform-independent** solution. Windows only.

```
std::string utf16_to_utf8(std::u16string u16_string)
{
    std::wstring wide_string(u16_string.begin(), u16_string.end());
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes(wide_string);
}
```