# Is Visual-C++-2017 binary compatible with VC++-2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-c++-2015, visual-c++-2017

[Steve tells me](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-54-Whats-New-In-Visual-Studio-2017-RC-and-Introduction-To-Vcpkg#time=25m46s) that VC 2015 and VC 2017 are actually (gonna be) *binary compatible*.

I found *zero* info wrt. this in the [release notes for 2017 (RC)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) - or pretty much anywhere for that matter, so here goes:

- Is a C++ (C++ interface) DLL built with [VC++-2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) binary compatible with a DLL built by VC++-2015?
- Do 2017 and 2015 use the same (dynamic) [runtime library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/)?
- If so, what, if any, is the *runtime* difference between Platform Toolset `Visual Studio 2017 (v141)` and `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`? (*)

---

(*): Yeah, I actually went ahead and installed the 2017 RC, and from what I can see on the surface, at least the *identical* MSVCRT is used, that is `msvcp140.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` (despite the platform toolset being called "v141".

Comment: MS has since added an "official" blurb: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, the 141 and 140 libraries are almost identical. The version was bumped for a side-by-side issue. The v140 toolset in VisualC++ 2015 and v141 toolset in VC++ 2017 are binary compatible.

Comment: Is this still the case for VS2017 15.3? We're getting linker errors ("different compiler version") with 2015 static libs now.

Comment: I'm unable to install **VC++2015Redist** on a machine that has **VC++2017Redist**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967479/can-visual-c-2017-redistributable-package-support-the-applications-that-use-vc

Comment: Kevin, are you using libraries compiled with /GL (link-time codegen)? Those are not supported across major compiler versions. They worked with 15.0-15.2, but that was just dumb luck.

Comment: @KevinRichardson Maybe this is supposed to work, but you're hitting the following bug? I'm getting this error myself: 
   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/112448/link-failure-with-vs2015-static-library-and-vs2017.html

Comment: Yes, we recently talked to Microsoft and it was the /GL issue.

Comment: To clarify @apardoe comment which points to the root of the issue, /GL (link-time codegen) is misleading.  In VS project settings, /GL is associated with "Whole Program Optimization", so look for that to disable.  LTCG is implied with /GL however. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation?view=vs-2017

Comment: @apardoe - Hi Andrew. Maybe you would like to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187152/is-the-official-binary-incompatibility-between-vs2017-and-vs2015-app-vs-dll-acc ... official docs confuse me some.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has been updating their CRT in an incremental manner.

Visual C++ 14.0 (2015) CRT has 4 files:

- vcruntime140.dll (C Runtime; from refactored msvcr*.dll)
- concrt140.dll (the Concurrency Runtime; also from msvcr*.dll)
- msvcp140.dll (C++ Runtime)
- vccorlib140.dll (C++/CX Platform::*)

Visual C++ 14.1 (2017) CRT adds only 2 files:

- vcruntime140_1.dll (seems like a patch to SEH in vcruntime140.dll)
- msvcp140_1.dll ([C++17 Polymorphic Memory Resources](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource))

Visual C++ 14.2 (2019) CRT adds only 2 files:

- msvcp140_2.dll ([C++17 Mathematical Special Functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions) and std::hypot(x, y, z))
- msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll (bug fix for std::codecvt; see [the Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055357/visual-studio-c-2015-stdcodecvt-with-char16-t-or-char32-t))

If some of the additional features listed above are not used, the binary can work with older versions of C Runtime.

Comment: Note that ``msvcp140_2.dll`` is actually in VS 2017 (added in an update), and ``vcruntime140_1.dll`` was added in VS 2019 to support a new x64 exception handling implementation (see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/making-cpp-exception-handling-smaller-x64/)).  Note that ``concrt140.dll`` is only used for Windows XP platform support for ``<future>``; it's not used on newer versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, visual 2019(14.2),2017(14.1),2015(14.0) are all binary compatible, they are all 14.x version. See more on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2017.
New versions add some new features or patches.

The following are the files in 2017 and 2019, you can find the new files added in 2019.

```sh
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\x64\Microsoft.VC141.CRT"
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 0CAC-076E

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\x64\Microsoft.VC141.CRT

2020-09-25  14:41    <DIR>          .
2020-09-25  14:41    <DIR>          ..
2020-09-25  14:41           332,568 concrt140.dll
2020-09-25  14:41           627,992 msvcp140.dll
2020-09-25  14:41            31,512 msvcp140_1.dll
2020-09-25  14:41           206,104 msvcp140_2.dll
2020-09-25  14:41           366,872 vccorlib140.dll
2020-09-25  14:41            85,784 vcruntime140.dll
               6 File(s)      1,650,832 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  57,822,343,168 bytes free

C:\Users\Liu.D.H>dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.27.29016\x64\Microsoft.VC142.CRT"
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 0CAC-076E

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.27.29016\x64\Microsoft.VC142.CRT

2020-09-25  13:07    <DIR>          .
2020-09-25  13:07    <DIR>          ..
2020-09-25  13:07           317,224 concrt140.dll
2020-09-25  13:07           590,632 msvcp140.dll
2020-09-25  13:07            31,528 msvcp140_1.dll
2020-09-25  13:07           193,832 msvcp140_2.dll
2020-09-25  13:07            27,936 msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll
2020-09-25  13:07           337,696 vccorlib140.dll
2020-09-25  13:07           101,672 vcruntime140.dll
2020-09-25  13:07            44,328 vcruntime140_1.dll
               8 File(s)      1,644,848 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  57,822,343,168 bytes free

C:\Users\Liu.D.H>
```

Because I can't install 2015 files. I extract it (`D:\apps\wix311-binaries\dark.exe -nologo -x "D:\tmp\vcredist_x64-2015" "C:\Users\Liu.D.H\Downloads\vc_redist.x64-2015.exe"`) and you can find the files below.

```sh
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/tmp/vcredist_x64-2015$ /usr/bin/tree .
.
├── AttachedContainer
│   └── packages
│       ├── Patch
│       │   ├── x64
│       │   │   ├── Windows6.0-KB2999226-x64.msu
│       │   │   ├── Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu
│       │   │   ├── Windows8-RT-KB2999226-x64.msu
│       │   │   └── Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu
│       │   └── x86
│       │       ├── Windows6.0-KB2999226-x86.msu
│       │       ├── Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu
│       │       ├── Windows8-RT-KB2999226-x86.msu
│       │       └── Windows8.1-KB2999226-x86.msu
│       ├── vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64
│       │   ├── cab1
│       │   │   ├── mfc140.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140chs.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140cht.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140deu.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140enu.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140esn.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140fra.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140ita.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140jpn.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140kor.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140rus.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfc140u.dll
│       │   │   ├── mfcm140.dll
│       │   │   └── mfcm140u.dll
│       │   ├── cab1.cab
│       │   └── vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi
│       └── vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64
│           ├── cab1
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_console_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_datetime_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_debug_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_errorhandling_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_file_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_file_l1_2_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_file_l2_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_handle_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_heap_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_interlocked_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_libraryloader_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_localization_l1_2_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_memory_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_namedpipe_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_processenvironment_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_processthreads_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_processthreads_l1_1_1.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_profile_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_rtlsupport_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_string_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_synch_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_synch_l1_2_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_sysinfo_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_timezone_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_core_util_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_conio_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_convert_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_environment_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_filesystem_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_heap_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_locale_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_math_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_multibyte_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_private_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_process_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_runtime_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_stdio_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_string_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_time_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── api_ms_win_crt_utility_l1_1_0.dll
│           │   ├── concrt140.dll
│           │   ├── msvcp140.dll
│           │   ├── ucrtbase.dll
│           │   ├── vcamp140.dll
│           │   ├── vccorlib140.dll
│           │   ├── vcomp140.dll
│           │   └── vcruntime140.dll
│           ├── cab1.cab
│           └── vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi
└── UX
    ├── 1028
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1029
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1031
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1036
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1040
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1041
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1042
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1045
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1046
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1049
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 1055
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 2052
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── 3082
    │   ├── license.rtf
    │   └── thm.wxl
    ├── BootstrapperApplicationData.xml
    ├── license.rtf
    ├── logo.png
    ├── manifest.xml
    ├── thm.wxl
    ├── thm.xml
    └── wixstdba.dll

23 directories, 106 files
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/tmp/vcredist_x64-2015$
```

The main files in 2015 are the following.

```
│           │   ├── concrt140.dll
│           │   ├── msvcp140.dll
│           │   ├── ucrtbase.dll
│           │   ├── vcamp140.dll
│           │   ├── vccorlib140.dll
│           │   ├── vcomp140.dll
│           │   └── vcruntime140.dll
```