# std::locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to learn different locales and handling unicode and I chose to make all my strings UTF-8 and I decided to run the following code but for some reason it throws an error and I cannot figure out why.. I tried every locale so far and none except "C" works.. I tried the list of locales found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/localization.html

and their example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>   what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Mingw-Builds gcc/g++ 4.8.1 with the latest codeblocks on Windows 8. Language is set to EN_US and sometimes I switch to EN_GB.

Comment: Do you have that local installed on your system? [Valid Locale Names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1922713/14065)

Comment: Do you have the same error with `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` See [std::locale breakage on MacOS 10.6 with LANG=en_US.UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745045/stdlocale-breakage-on-macos-10-6-with-lang-en-us-utf-8)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "installed locale" but my system language is en_US and sometimes I switch it to en_GB. Using `std::locale("")` prints `C` and I don't have that error.

Comment: Old compiler version.

Comment: Gcc/g++ 4.8.1 Window with the latest codeblocks. I'll add all this to the OP.

Comment: Strange, because it runs online on 4.8.1 but fails on 4.3.2 -http://ideone.com/4bAjfv

Comment: `$ g++ --version
g++.exe (rev0, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Still same error. I don't know why. I guess it just doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't that just because of MinGW locale support being incomplete?

Comment: MingW on Windows? You may try Windows locale name, like ".936" (which is for Chinese). Always thought locale names also depend on the system, not on compiler/library only. Haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into same problem last week, I wrote a program to print all supported locale names under Windows OS.

See my answer [Print all std::locale names (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614666/print-all-stdlocale-names-windows/27615711#27615711)

Locale that you are looking for is just "en-US" under Windows.