# Print all std::locale names (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, boost, locale

My program checks for uppercase letters in German language.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    locale::global(locale("Germany_german"));
    //locale::global(locale("de_DE.UTF-8")); //Also tried "de_DE.UTF-8", but does not work

    string str1 = "über";
    cout << boolalpha << any_of(str1.begin(), str1.end(), boost::algorithm::is_upper()) << endl;

    string str2 = "Ää";
    cout << boolalpha << any_of(str2.begin(), str2.end(), boost::algorithm::is_upper()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

program crashes with error on console

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

I don't know what that exact locale string is, "de_DE.UTF-8" doesn't work as well.

Is there any way I can get exact locale name strings for all locales supported by OS.  May be there is a list somewhere in header files, but I don't see anything `<locale>` header.

Comment: You can do `locale -a` on a command line.

Comment: "de-DE" and "German_Germany" should work. At least, you should be able to construct `locale` from these strings.

Comment: As to enumerating locales, see `EnumSystemLocalesEx`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just tried what you suggested. I am not able to construct locale, compiler throws exception right on locale::global line.

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/MCE50195)

Comment: In which encoding your source file is saved ? UTF8 ?

Comment: under C:B, it is UTF-8

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I wrote a program to print all supported locale names.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

vector<wstring> locals;

BOOL CALLBACK MyFuncLocaleEx(LPWSTR pStr, DWORD dwFlags, LPARAM lparam)
{
    locals.push_back(pStr);
    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    EnumSystemLocalesEx(MyFuncLocaleEx, LOCALE_ALL, NULL, NULL);

    for (vector<wstring>::const_iterator str = locals.begin(); str != locals.end(); ++str)
        wcout << *str << endl;

    wcout << "Total " << locals.size() << " locals found." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Works great.

```
...
de
de-AT
de-CH
de-DE
de-DE_phoneb
de-LI
de-LU
...    
Total 429 locals found.
```

Comment: This looks like a pretty useful snippet of code. Thanks for sharing your answer

Comment: Interesting, for some reason my compiler cannot find `EnumSystemLocalesEx`. Altough I include `windows.h`.

Comment: @Julien Looks like there is some change in API. Try including Winnls.h

Comment: @user1 Nevermind; for whatever reasons, my local MinGW does not support 'EnumSystemLocalesEx', as it cannot be found anywhere in their development files.

Comment: Tried compiling with <Winnls.h>. Receive a C1189 error "#error: 'No Target Architecture'" on line 173 of <Winnls.h>. The code is interesting, wish I could use it, but I still need to understand and implement something that allows put_money to work. I did try to use locale("en-US" ) with no success. From cplusplus.com and other sites, I believe locale mylocale("") should default to the regional locale, in my case the US. But, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @user1 for me the code ran when I made 2 updates, 1. #include <tchar.h>, 2. Change second null, EnumSystemLocalesEx(MyFuncLocaleEx, LOCALE_ALL, 0, NULL);

Answer (score 0):

@user1 The following might do the same as your elegant code. I can't test it because of the C1189 compiler error.

```
#include <Winnls.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int size = 0;

BOOL CALLBACK MyFuncLocaleEx(LPWSTR pStr, DWORD dwFlags, LPARAM lparam) {
    size++;
    wcout << *pStr << endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    EnumSystemLocalesEx(MyFuncLocaleEx, LOCALE_ALL, NULL, NULL);
    wcout << "Total " << size << " locales found." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```