# Why boost locale didn't provide character level rule type?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Env: boost1.53.0 c++11;

New to c++.

In boost locale boundary analysis, the rule type is specified for word(eg.`boundary::word_letter`, `boundary::word_number`) and sentence , but there is no boundary rule type for character. All I want is something like `isUpperCase(), isLowerCase(), isDigit(), isPunctuation()`.

Tried boost string algorithm which didn't work.

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen("ru_RU.UTF-8");
std::string context = "ДВ";
std::cout << boost::algorithm::all(context, boost::algorithm::is_upper(loc));
```

Why these features can be accessed easily in Java or python but so so confusing in C++? Any consist way to achieve these?

Comment: what do you mean by "boost string algorithm which didn't work", your program crashes?

Comment: = =! It doesn't work as expected. Wrong result. It can only handle ascii letter.  Thanks again~

Comment: Which operating system? What is the code page your source file is saved in?

Comment: unbuntu 12.04. Everything is encoded with utf8.

Comment: Take a look at program in the question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614666/print-all-stdlocale-names-windows/27615711#27615711. Very similar to what you are attempting and it works fine. Just change it according to your program, change locale ofcourse, see if it works

Comment: Are 100% sure about the locale "ru_RU.UTF-8". How did you find out the correct locale. You must use locale -a command to find out all locales supported and then chose appropriately.

Comment: I tried `locale -a`, and find out `ru_RU.UTF-8` is not installed. After `locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8`, recompile and run, still no luck!

Comment: If a locale name is not right. A bad_cast exception would be thrown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67822/discussion-between-user1-and-tilney).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me under VS 2013.

```
locale::global(locale("ru-RU")); 
std::string context = "ДВ"; 
std::cout << any_of(context.begin(), context.end(), boost::algorithm::is_upper());
```

Prints `1`

It is important how you initialize the locale.

**UPDATE**:

Here's solution which will work under Ubuntu.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    locale::global(locale("ru_RU"));

    wstring context = L"ДВ";
    wcout << boolalpha << any_of(context.begin(), context.end(), boost::algorithm::is_upper());

    wcout<<endl;

    wstring context1 = L"ПРИВЕТ, МИР"; //HELLO WORLD in russian
    wcout << boolalpha << any_of(context1.begin(), context1.end(), boost::algorithm::is_upper());

    wcout<<endl;

    wstring context2 = L"привет мир"; //hello world in russian
    wcout << boolalpha << any_of(context2.begin(), context2.end(), boost::algorithm::is_upper());

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
true
true
false
```

This will work with boost::algorithm::all as well.

```
wstring context = L"ДВ";
wcout << boolalpha << boost::algorithm::all(context, boost::algorithm::is_upper());
```

Comment: It works for me finally. In fact, this is part of my named entity tagging project. From sentence segmentation, tokenization to named entity tagging, the whole pipeline is uniformed in `unicode string` and the basic character unit is a utf8 char. And according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring , `wstring` is preferred under windows, but not with linux. Anyway, if there is no other option, then it has to be this way. And thanks for everything!

Comment: I post another way blow to achieve this. Check it out if interested.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.locale is based on ICU and ICU itself did provide character level classification, which seems pretty consist and readable(more of Java-style).

Here is a simple example.

```
#include <unicode/brkiter.h>
#include <unicode/utypes.h>
#include <unicode/uchar.h>

int main()
{
UnicodeString s("А аБ Д д2 -");
UErrorCode status = U_ERROR_WARNING_LIMIT;
Locale ru("ru", "RU");
BreakIterator* bi = BreakIterator::createCharacterInstance(ru, status);
bi->setText(s);
int32_t p = bi->first();
while(p != BreakIterator::DONE) {
    std::string type;
    if(u_isUUppercase(s.charAt(p)))
        type = "upper" ;
    if(u_isULowercase(s.charAt(p)))
        type = "lower" ;
    if(u_isUWhiteSpace(s.charAt(p)))
        type = "whitespace" ;
    if(u_isdigit(s.charAt(p)))
        type = "digit" ;
    if(u_ispunct(s.charAt(p)))
        type = "punc" ;
    printf("Boundary at position %d is %s\n", p, type.c_str());
    p= bi->next();
}
delete bi;
return 0;
```

}